# Is there issues with NPM, Are these big issues in my program?

Tags: node.js, database, frontend, node-modules, audit

"When I try to install dependencies or start my development server from react-scripts its give warning and errors, I have tried reinstalling, checking npmjs.org for better installs, how can I fix these warnings and deprecations? I also have installed bootstrap and web=pack, and it also fails to let me install -g windows-build-tools I also tried using an administrator terminal. Then it just sits and says installing forever and never finishes, lost at what to do. any packages or dependencies I'm missing? I have connected to ganache and meta mask also. with truffle framework."

PS C:\Users\Noahm\ethswap>   npm audit fix

```
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit to fix ini@1.3.5 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm, WARN audit to fix ini@1.3.5 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
npm, WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/minimalist
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar
npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/mkdirp
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
[..................] / : WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/mkdirp
```

Comment: I'm facing this same issue, any update on this?